# Comparing contents of two arrays, receiving error that "Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'"

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

What I'm trying to do is return the top 2 categories, then compare those to the "userCategory" array, and see if there are any matching categories. It successfully returns the top 2, but can't seem to recognize the userCategory array.

Ideally what I want is for every user to have multiple instances of the userCategory object (one for smartphones, one for shoes, etc.). It seems that creating it as an array may be incorrect, as it's not initializing properly. Any help is appreciated!

The full error message:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'
    at main.js:60:33
    at Array.some (native)
    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:59:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:571:19)
```

Here's my JS function:

```
// Sends search query to eBay

Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url,
      params: {     
       'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
       'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
       'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
       'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
       'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
       'keywords' : request.params.item,

     },
      success: function (httpResponse) {


// parses results

          var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
          var items = [];

          response.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function(itemByKeywordsResponse) {
            itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function(result) {
              result.item.forEach(function(item) {
                items.push(item);
              });
            });
          });


// count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), return top two


          var categoryResults = {};

          items.forEach(function(item) {
            var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
            if (categoryResults[id]) categoryResults[id]++;
            else categoryResults[id] = 1;
          });

          var top2 = Object.keys(categoryResults).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return categoryResults[b]-categoryResults[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top two categories: ' + top2.join(', '));



// compare categoryResults to userCategory object

          var userCategory = {};

          var AnyItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory = Object.keys(categoryResults).some(function(item) {
            return userCategory.indexOf(item) > -1;
          });
          console.log(AnyItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory);

          var ItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory = Object.keys(categoryResults).filter(function(item) {
            return userCategory.indexOf(item) > -1;
          });
          console.log(ItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory);




  },
            error: function (httpResponse) {
                console.log('error!!!');
                console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
       });
});
```

Line 60 that it references is this one:

```
return userCategory.indexOf(item) > -1;
```

Comment: `indexOf` is a method of arrays, not objects, you want to use a simple lookup with bracket notation, or the `in` operator.

Comment: 2 lines above the one in error you have `var userCategory = {};`. Doesn't look like an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined userCategory as an object, which doesn't have the method `indexOf`.

```
var userCategory = {};
```

You should declare the userCategory as an array.

```
var userCategory = [];
```

In your code the `categoryResults[id]` isn't adding an object to an array, but it is creating a property on your object.

To add an object to the array you can use:

```
userCategory.push(yourObjectHere)
```

Comment: Will this make it so that the userCategory array is mutable, and can have things added to it over time? Also, making this change now presents me with the following error: 

`Failed with: success/error was not called
I2014-04-14T18:34:09.856Z] Top two categories: 20349, 9355
I2014-04-14T18:34:09.856Z] false
I2014-04-14T18:34:09.857Z] []`

Comment: You can add an object to the array with userCategory.push(yourObjectHere)